# How to update widgets from a service?

Tags: android, widget

I have a background service that can be configured to perform some action every x minutes. I want to implement a widget that gets updated every time my service performs that action. However, I can't get the onUpdate method of my AppWidgetProvider called in any way, except when adding a widget to the homescreen.

I tried sending APPWIDGET_UPDATE intents but onUpdate did not get called although the AppWidgetProvider did receive the intent since the onReceive method was called. Is there any way I can trigger widget updates from a service?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just make yourself a `RemoteViews` and update the widget(s) directly in the `Service`. You'll get your `AppWidgetManager` via:

```
AppWidgetManager mgr=AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
```

Everything else is as normal.

**Note:-** If you really want to force the existing `AppWidgetProvider` to do the work, send a broadcast with a custom action to your component, and call `onUpdate()` yourself from `onReceive()` when you get it.

Comment: Thanks! The second suggestion is what I did and it works like a charm. Why didn't I think of that myself ... :)

Comment: onUpdate needs an array int[] appWidgetIds as argument.  How do you calculate it when you are in the onReceive method ?

Comment: @Guido: Call `getAppWidgetIds()` on `AppWidgetManager`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html

Comment: @CommonsWare so what if you have multiple types of widgets; this way the code isnt very extensible because you'll have to fetch ids and update the views for all of your widget types manually? (not that you'll have dozens of different types ofc)